# .NET Restful WCF Http Web Service for use w/ ASP.NET MVC3 and anything else

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest

I am building a big ASP.NET MVC3 web site. I am going to hit a big backend database and have lots of webservices. I plan on exposing the webservices publicly down the line as an restful API that will consume/return JSON or XML.

Would it be best to keep my webservices as a completely seperate project and should I use pure WCF for them?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would certainly consider keeping the Services project separate from the Web Site Project.

As for which framework to use I would check out the [WCF HTTP project](http://wcf.codeplex.com/), [OpenRasta](https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-core), or straight .NET MVC.